# How to carry a value through scanf to a function

Tags: c, input, scanf

I have a quick question in the program I'm trying to create.  I can't seem to figure out how I can carry through the value that someone inputs for my variable of "denom" so that it can be successfully used in the function I've created. Help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Global Variables
int num, denom;
void simplify(int *numerator, int *denominator);

int main () {
    int num1, denom1;
    //Prompt User as to what program is
    printf("Fraction Simplifier\n");
    printf("===================\n");

    //Ask User for Numerator and Denominator
    printf("Numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &denom);

    //Call Function
    simplify(&num1, &denom1);

    //Display final output
    printf("%d / %d = %d / %d\n", num, denom, num1, denom1);

    return 0;
}

//Simplify function
void simplify(int *numerator, int *denominator)
{

    int num1, denom1;
    num1 = 1;
    num = num1;
    denom = denom1;

    num1 = num1 / num1;
    denom1 = denom1 / num1;
    *numerator = num1 ;
    *denominator = denom1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `simplify()` method doesn't even try to use the passed values.

It boils down to *numerator = 1 and *denominator = is undefined (since denom1 is never initialized). i.e. it sets "out values" to "constants". You probably meant to do something like:

```
int num1 = *numerator;
int denom1 = *denominator;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Simplify() function:

```
*int num1, denom1;             
denom = denom1;* (1)
denom1 = denom1 / num1; (2)
*denominator = denom1;* (3)
```

in (1) denom1 has undefined values. So when you use:
(2)denom1 still has an undefined value
and in (3)
denominator has an undefined value